# I got a syntax error that says EOL while scanning string literal why?

Tags: python

I get an error on line 8 EOL while scanning string literal.

I've already tried indenting the line and adding a backslash but nothing is working.

class HumanPlayer(Player):

```
def move(self):

    move_choice = input('rock, paper, scissors, SHOOT! >')

    while move_choice != 'rock'and move_choice != '
    'paper'and move_choice != 'scissors':
        print('Sorry that entry is invalid, please try again')
        move_choice = input('rock, paper, scissors,SHOOT! >')
    return (move_choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra `'` and didn't complete the `while` statement on the line you started it. Since you want it spanning multiple line add a `\`, this is called and explicit line continuation

```
def move(self):

    move_choice = input('rock, paper, scissors, SHOOT! >')

    while move_choice != 'rock'and move_choice != \
    'paper'and move_choice != 'scissors':
        print('Sorry that entry is invalid, please try again')
        move_choice = input('rock, paper, scissors,SHOOT! >')

    return (move_choice)
```